# Get the selected item from dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, menu

what is the best way to get the selected item from dropdown menu?

My dropdown menu is generated inside while loop if that matters :)

P.s. before you down-vote...I tried a couple of techniques I found on google and on this website.

Here is example of my dropdown menu:

```
<select id="select1">
<?php
$id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=$id>$row[0]</option>";
    $id++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: you need to give that select a `name`

Comment: replace `"<option value=$id>$row[0]</option>"` with `'<option value="' . $id . '">' . $row[0] . '</option>'` and name your select as Dale says

Comment: +1 to offset, this is not a bad question.

Comment: if PHP then get selected item by name, if javascript get selected item by id or name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it a `name`:

```
<select id="select1" name="myselect">
<?php
$id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$id\">{$row[0]}</option>";
    $id++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Then, when posted, you have the value available in `$_REQUEST['myselect']`.

Comment: Don't use $_REQUEST. Use $_POST.

Comment: @Prisoner, hard to tell if I don't have the poster's `<form>` tag. Perhaps he `GET`s the data.

Comment: True, but you said "when posted" so I assumed you'd assumed he was posting his data :)

Comment: Ok, Ive added name to my select, used $_REQUEST['myselect'] to get selected value, but when I print it nothing shows up.

Comment: @a2567429 could you post your entire form code, and where you use your results? A lot can be wrong here.

Comment: Well my form looks like this:

    <form action="ThisPage.php" method="POST">
    <textarea rows=5 cols=40 name="text"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>

I have my dropdown menus above this form.

Comment: Your `<select>` should be inside your form.

Comment: Well I have 2 select menus, I dont want to redirect after they selected something in the first one..

Comment: The "redirect" will only happen when the submit button is pushed.

Comment: O I see what you mean, so I need to make a form and place both of my dropdown menus inside it?

Comment: if you want to receive values of both lists, yes.